# Real world problem with parabola (Springboard high dive)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ana dives into a pool off of a springboard high dive.
Her height (in meters above the water), $x$ seconds after diving, is modeled by $$h(x)=-5(x+1)(x-3)$$

**How many seconds after diving will Ana hit the water?**

*My solution:* First I found $x$ for $y(x)=0$ it's $x=-1s,x=3s$ , then I found max. height above the water $y({-1+3\over2})=20m$ , in conclusion to reach $0m$ from $20m$ need $3s-1s=2s$. My answer is $2s.$, but according khanacademy, right answer is $3s$. Which answer is right?

[image: graph]

Comment: Ana is standing on a 15m diving board at $x=0$ seconds. She leaps 5m into the air and splashes down after 3 seconds. This is 2 seconds after she reached that maximum height. Ana is a crazy person.

Comment: Is the confusion here in the meaning of the term 'after diving'? What you seem to have calculated is how long it took Ana to splash **since she reached the highest point**. Khanacademy probably measure the time **since she leapt**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Her height above water is $h(x)$. She hits the water when $h(x)=0$. Since the only solutions of $h(x)=0$ are $x=-1$ and $x=3$, the correct answer is $x=3$ seconds (the answer $x=-1$ is nonsense, since time does not run backwards).